# Creating an Elapsed Time calculated field in a pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, calculated-field

I have a date timestamp in Column A and want to create a new calculated column that displays the elapsed time between NOW and the values in Column A. THANK YOU for any help with this one.

Comment: You can't use NOW in a calculated field. One option might be to use it in a regular helper column on the worksheet.

Comment: Thanks I didn’t think I could ...